# processing opencv image pixels quickly using python interface

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Using python-interface for OpenCV, one can easily access the pixel of image using [] operator,like this:

```
img = cv.LoadImage('test.jpg')
pixel = img[10,10]
```

variable **pixel** here is a **python tuple** object like **(10,20,30)** (3 channels for example), it's not very convenient to process computation since **tuple type does not support operator '-' or '+'**. If I hope to do a substruction on a pixel like **255 - (10,20,30)**, I must
code like this:

```
import numpy as np
pixel = tuple( np.array([255,255,255]) - np.array(pixel) )
```

is there a faster and easier solution? 
Another qustion : is there a way to make a substraction on all pixels, like using a matrix substraction in Matlab: **255 - img** (don't use OpenCV build-in function).

Answer (score 3):

You could use `cv2array()/array2cv()` functions from adaptors.py in the opencv source distribution and perform all your computation using `numpy` arrays. `255 - imgarr` works in this case. Example (stripped-down version of `cv2array()` for read-only arrays):

```
assert isinstance(img, cv.iplimage) and img.depth == cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U
a = np.frombuffer(img.tostring(), dtype=np.uint8)
a.shape = img.height, img.width, img.nChannels
print 255 - a
```

Comment: my opencv version is 2.1, I found adaptors.py in \OpenCV2.1\interfaces\swig\python, and there was not a function called cv2array() or array2cv()

Comment: @PinkyJie: http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=function%3Acv2array+file%3Aadaptors.py+lang%3Apython&hl=en&btnG=Search+Code

Comment: @PinkyJie: On the other hand the above method might be outdated. Does your version have `cv.fromarray()` function? What do you get on `numpy.asarray(img)`? http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html#numpy-and-opencv

Comment: I installed opencv using "OpenCV-2.1.0-win32-vs2008.exe", a pre-compiled edition, so no cv.fromarray() function, and numpy.asarray(img) return a iplimage object array, not numpy.ndarray.

Comment: @PinkyJie: I've added example code in case `np.asarray()` doesn't return anything useful.